# Getting ESLint error: Parsing error: ',' expected

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I get an ESLint error on `links.length` - `',' expected`. Wasn't able to fix it with `npx eslint . --fix`:

```
const FooterLinkColumn: FC<IFooterLinkColumn> = ({
    title,
    links
}) => {
    const { t } = useTranslation(['common']);
    const { defaultLanguage } = useAppSelector(shopSelector);

    return (
        {links.length ? (
            links.map((link) => (
                <Link
                    href={getContentHrefUrl()}
                    as={getContentUrl({
                        publicId: link.publicId, translations: { [defaultLanguage]: { slug: link.slug } }
                    } as IContentPage, defaultLanguage)}
                >
                    <a 
                        className={styles.footer__link}
                        data-testid={link.title.split('.')[1]}
                    >
                        {t(link.title)}    
                    </a>        
                </Link>
            ))
        ) : null}
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an eslint error. You should remove unnecessary brackets.

```
  return (
      links.length ? (
          links.map((link) => (
              <Link
                  href={getContentHrefUrl()}
                  as={getContentUrl({
                      publicId: link.publicId, translations: { [defaultLanguage]: { slug: link.slug } }
                  } as IContentPage, defaultLanguage)}
              >
                  <a 
                      className={styles.footer__link}
                      data-testid={link.title.split('.')[1]}
                  >
                      {t(link.title)}    
                  </a>        
              </Link>
          ))
      ) : null
  )
```